# Open Abaqus odb file independently in python

Tags: python, output, abaqus, post-processing

I was wondering is it possible to open an "odb" file (results of an Abaqus analysis) with python without using Abaqus? Such as open it with a python interpreter (ex, spyder) and just take out some results from it? without opening abaqus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Abaqus output database (called ODB file) is a binary file and I don't think you can read it outside Abaqus unless you know the encryption of it. 
However, there are some alternatives available.

1. Using `abaqus python <Abaqus python script name>` method to run the your Abaqus python script in Powershell/Command Prompt for windows users and in terminal for Linux users. But, this command requires Abaqus to be installed in your system. And there are some limitations like you can work only with the ODB file (not with .CAE files), you cannot use GUI related commands, etc..
2. Using open source module called [abapy](https://abapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#introduction)

For 2nd method, you first need to save the ODB data using `pickle` module using Abaqus python. Then we can post-process it using `abapy` or any other open source Python module. However, this is recommended when you're doing extensive post-processing.